# onOptionsItemSelected() method not get called on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an **AppCompatActivity** and some Fragments. The back button on the action bar not works on in `AboutFragment`.

The Activity has no menu inflated, while the Fragment only has a back button in the action bar.

Fragment menu is visible, but the back button doesn't react at all when tapped.

The `AboutFragment` is getting showed on clicking the info icon from the actionbar.

[image: the <code>AboutFragment</code> is getting showed on clicking the info icon from the actionbar]

While clicking on the `i` icon, the bellow method works inside `MainActivity`.

```
 @Override
    public void onInfoSelected() {

        abf = (AboutFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
       // ft.hide(pf);

        //ft.hide(cf);
        ft.hide(tlf);
        ft.show(abf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

then the back button inside AboutFragment doesn't call `onOptionsItemSelected()` method inside the Fragment.

[image]

When debugging, I can see that both `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for Fragment and Activity get called, but when tapping buttons no `onOptionsItemSelected()` gets called, neither from Activity nor from Fragment.

its been two days I am searching and googling, nothing worked for me.
any help would be appriciated.

**Activity Java code**

```
package me.declangao.jiasazsales.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import me.declangao.jiasazsales.R;
import me.declangao.jiasazsales.model.Post;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        RecyclerViewFragment.PostListListener, PostFragment.PostListener,
        TabLayoutFragment.TabLayoutListener, SearchResultFragment.SearchResultListener,
        CommentFragment.CommentListener,AboutFragment.AboutListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAB_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "TabLayoutFragment";
    public static final String POST_FRAGMENT_TAG = "PostFragment";
    public static final String COMMENT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "CommentFragment";

    public static final String ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "AboutFragment";


    private FragmentManager fm = null;
    private TabLayoutFragment tlf;
    private PostFragment pf;
    private CommentFragment cf;
    private SearchResultFragment srf;
    private AboutFragment abf;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Setup fragments
        tlf = new TabLayoutFragment();
        pf = new PostFragment();
        cf = new CommentFragment();
        srf = new SearchResultFragment();
        abf=new AboutFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, abf, ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, pf, POST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, cf, COMMENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, tlf, TAB_LAYOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);


        ft.hide(pf);
        ft.hide(cf);
        ft.hide(abf);
        ft.show(tlf);
        ft.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when a post in the list is selected
     *
     * @param post Selected Post object
     */
    @Override
    public void onPostSelected(Post post, boolean isSearch) {
        // Find the fragment in order to set it up later
        pf = (PostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(POST_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        // Set necessary arguments
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", post.getId());
        args.putString("title", post.getTitle());
        args.putString("date", post.getDate());
        args.putString("author", post.getAuthor());
        args.putString("content", post.getContent());
        args.putString("url", post.getUrl());
        //args.putString("thumbnailUrl", post.getThumbnailUrl());
        args.putString("featuredImage", post.getFeaturedImageUrl());

        // Configure PostFragment to display the right post
        pf.setUIArguments(args);

        // Show the fragment
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        if (!isSearch) { // Hide TabLayoutFragment if this is not search result
            ft.hide(tlf);

        } else { // Otherwise, hide the search result, ie. SearchResultFragment.
            ft.hide(srf);
        }
        ft.show(pf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //do something here like
Log.e("menu Test","rom Main activity");
                int backStackEntryCount
                        =getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

                if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {

                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                }

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Invoked when a search query is submitted
     *
     * @param query Selected Post object
     */
    @Override
    public void onSearchSubmitted(String query) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        // Send query to fragment using factory method
        srf = SearchResultFragment.newInstance(query);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, srf);
        ft.hide(tlf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onInfoSelected() {

        abf = (AboutFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
       // ft.hide(pf);

        //ft.hide(cf);
        ft.hide(tlf);
        ft.show(abf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
    /**
     * Invoked when comment menu is selected
     *
     * @param id ID of the article, assigned by WordPress
     */
    @Override
    public void onCommentSelected(int id) {
        cf = (CommentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(COMMENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", id);
        // Setup CommentFragment to display the right comments page
        cf.setUIArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.hide(pf);
        //ft.hide(abf);
        ft.show(cf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Intercept back button event, reset ActionBar if necessary
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        resetActionBarIfApplicable();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    /**
     * Simulate a back button press when home is selected
     */
    @Override
    public void onHomePressed() {
        resetActionBarIfApplicable();
        fm.popBackStack();
    }

    /**
     * Reset TabLayoutFragment's ActionBar if necessary
     */
    private void resetActionBarIfApplicable() {
        Log.d(TAG, "SearchResultFragment is visible: " + srf.isHidden());
        if (srf.isVisible()) {
            tlf.resetActionBar();
        }
    }

    // Commented out coz we will let fragments handle their own Options Menus
/*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        //Log.e("Erroraaa","aaaaa");

        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Log.e("menu","activity: action home has clicked");
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:

                onBackPressed();
                return false;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
*/

}
```

**AboutFragment**

```
 package me.declangao.jiasazsales.app;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import me.declangao.jiasazsales.R;

/**
 * Fragment to display a Info about Jiasaz company.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link AboutFragment.AboutListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 */
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {



    private AboutListener mListener;
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);

        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
//        Log.e("Menu:created","Menu");
//
////        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
////        menu.clear();
//        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
//        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
//    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("Menu:selected","Menu");
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            mListener.onHomePressed();
        }
        return false;
    }


    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_layout, container, false);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(  "www.Jiasaz.com");
         Log.e("Menu: fragment created","onCreaate()");

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (AboutListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement AboutListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface AboutListener {
       void onHomePressed();
        //void onInfoSelected();
    }




}
```

**and this is my AboutFragment xml code**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"

    tools:context="me.declangao.jiasazsales.app.AboutFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="ئه‌م ئاپه‌ له‌لایه‌ن كۆمپانیای جیاساز دروست كراوه‌"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="214dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jiasazlogo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="كۆمپانیای جیاساز بۆ خزمه‌تگوزاری و چاره‌سه‌ری ته‌كنه‌لۆجی، دروستكردنی وێبسایت و ئاپی مۆبایل و سیسته‌می دام و ده‌زگاكان و ماركێته‌كان"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/link"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an instance of `OnMenuItemClickListener` directly on the `Toolbar`. Remember that you **should not use** `Activity.setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`.

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

    // ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_layout, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_about_fragment);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.some_menu) {
                    // do sth...
                    return true; // event is handled.
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

.

### UPDATE 21/11/2018:

To enable back button for a stand alone `Toolbar`, set its default icon in `xml` file using `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

Then set a listener for it

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // back button is pressed
        mListener.onHomePressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` after `toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener`?

Comment: No I call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` then ` toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener`

Comment: Try to not to use `setSupportActionBar` then test the updated solution.

Comment: It crashed my application

Comment: remove these lines: ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(  "www.Jiasaz.com");

Comment: Is your theme for the activity in the manifest something other than `NoActionBar`?

Comment: now the back button is disabled, can not even click on it

Comment: Its `NoActionBar`

Comment: Do you sure you're setting `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` for the toolbar?

Comment: Yes i did, its still the same

Comment: It's a weird situation :-| I've wrote a sample project and it works fine. Let's check another thing. uncomment those 4 lines to set the toolbar as actionbar. then use `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener`.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/aminography/FragmentToolbar and compare with your own.

Comment: I worked. Using this `setNavigationOnClickListener` I could handle the click listener, but dont know what to do if I have more than one menu item there.

Comment: It's a good news. It means that the conflict with actionbar is solved. Now you can show the menu (as first part of answer) using `toolbar.inflateMenu` and listen to item clicks by `toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener`.

Comment: Please check the git project again. (I have added menu items)

Answer (score 0):

You described everything properly, those are limitations of the platform. To workaround it you need to use onOptionsItemSelected()
in MainActivity, insert there code that you already use in another method:

```
abf = (AboutFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

then as you have the fragment you can invoke some method from the fragment and possibly get return value to know if the back is handled or not and if something more needs to be done...

Comment: As you have seen it is Activity onOptionsItemSelected() that is called. It has information on the id of the menu item. As id is unique you can know what is happening, whether it is from activity or fragment. If you need to handle it in the fragment you can use the code above. So this works, I am not sure exactly what you wanted say, it could be that from some theoretical point this isn't perfect, but that's the way to make it work as SDK isn't working as one would expect.

Comment: I even can not get the action on the activity `onOptionsItemSelected()` , its not showing any action anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` in you fragment class for listening to you action bar menus...

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    // to get an item of menu from action bar you can do it like...
    // this below line will find an item of menu with id action_search...
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    // like this you can find other menu items
    // another example is
    MenuItem infoMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
}
```

I'm using search view in my fragment class practically for searching...

Comment: this does not work on clicking the menu item , it only works when the fragment starts

Answer (score -1):

**First reason** is that you have'nt properly implemented `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` @Override methods in `Activity` so uncomment that `Activity` can also call their respective `super` methods.

**Second reason** is that your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` code is commented which needs `not` to be. Important thing is that super   `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` must be called to draw the menu of the `Fragment`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

And also change change `onOptionsItemSelected()` in `Fragment` to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.e("Menu:selected","Menu");
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        mListener.onHomePressed();
        return true;
    }else{
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And now in `Activity` change your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

and `onOptionsItemSelected()` to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already done this if you check the question.

Comment: tested it, the same as before, nothing happened, the onCreateOptionsMenu gets called, but the problem is with onOptionsItemSelected() which never gets called.

Comment: @rabarkareem also uncomment Activity `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` with their respective `super`s. Updated the answer again kindly replace the above given methods in respective classes and try

Comment: Also not worked, do you want me to send you the source code?